# Bar-plot does not show bar for only one x value

Tags: r, plotly

I am having an issue with a `plotly` bar plot when I define the date range for the x-axis.

When there is one or more data points with the same x-value, the bars do not show in the plot. If there is at least two different x-values or if I do not use a x-axis range, then the bars show as they should.

Below follows an example (I am currently using `lubridate` to deal with dates).

```r
library(lubridate)
library(plotly)

# Same x-value: bar does not show
plot_ly(x = c(ymd("2019-08-25"), ymd("2019-08-25")), y = c(1, 2), type = "bar") %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(range = ymd(c("2019-08-20", "2019-08-30"))))

# Different x-values: bars are shown
plot_ly(x = c(ymd("2019-08-25"), ymd("2019-08-26")), y = c(1, 2), type = "bar") %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(range = ymd(c("2019-08-20", "2019-08-30"))))

# No x-axis range defined, same x-values: the bar is shown
plot_ly(x = c(ymd("2019-08-25"), ymd("2019-08-25")), y = c(1, 2), type = "bar")
```

Any solution?

**Edit:** For comparison, `ggplot2` does not have the same issue:

```r
# ggplot works like expected
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(NULL, aes(x = ymd(c("2019-08-25", "2019-08-25")), y = c(1, 2))) +
    geom_col() +
    xlim(ymd(c("2019-08-20", "2019-08-30")))
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? When you have 2 values for the same bar, do they have to add up to one bar? Or do you wish 2 bars who stack onto each other?

Comment: @Arcoutte They will add up as default (like in example 3). If the data points have a third feature bond to `color` parameter they would stack, in which case I use `layout(barmode = "stack", ...)`. But I chose to use a minimal working example for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is actually being understood in your first version, but you need to set the width of the bars so they show up in the end.

I'm not sure what the units are (maybe miliseconds???) so you may need to play around with it or do research to get a good width for your actual scenario.

```
plot_ly() %>%
  add_bars(x = c(ymd("2019-08-25"), ymd("2019-08-25")), y = c(1, 2), type = "bar",width=100000000)%>%
  layout(xaxis = list(range = ymd(c("2019-08-20", "2019-08-30"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked just fine! So, it seems it is better to use `plotly::add_*` functions as the `plot_ly(..., width)` changes the width of the plot, not of the bars.
I am working with day units. As 1 day = 8.64e+7 ms, `width = 6.5e+7` was enough to give some spacing between bars.